# php htmlentities showing utf-8 encoded characters

Tags: php

Please hove on the first thumbnail here: http://dev.holiday.ge/?s=bar

`??????` will be displayed. This is utf-8 text and I run it through php `htmlentities()`

Can someone explain what is happening?

Do I have to encode htmlentities to make it display utf-8 text display correctly?

Any thoughts?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");

Comment: Can you please describe more exactly where on this page you are seeing this issue?

Comment: @jimcavoli Hi, I updated my question with screenshot.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce throughout the course of this question; glad @GBD had a working solution for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that my comment helped to fixed your issue.

Here is as answer

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the field's Collation is utf8_general_ci also have you used

Also have you added this code after you  select the DB by using mysql_select_db('dbName');

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
```

Comment it pls.

Comment: Hi, I use wordpress all these is handled by cms automatically.